# Copy paste file from share path to Desktop. And open the same from pasted location

Tags: javascript, html, copy

If a button is clicked,  it should copy a file from common share path and paste it on the Desktop. Also I want it to open that file from Desktop once it is there. I need a `<Html>` code. I am struggling to get this. Kindly help.

Comment: Always include some code how far you tried by yourself. Btw I'm not sure if you can do this with JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can't and you shouldn't. JavaScript from the browser can't access the filesystem directly and that is good.

Comment: I can open a file from Share path...But I could not copy file in that path to local desktop...I think It can happen using Java <script>...Pls correct me If I am wrong

Comment: What is the "Share path" ? YOu could probably do this with java but I advise strictly against it.

Comment: We will use this in secure place only So no issues in that. Sorry I can not share the Path details..